# What is a fork's single point called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A fork usually has three points; what are the individual points called? Trident points?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the correct word is *[tine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tine)*, but you will be understood if you say *prong* or something similar.